# Code first strange table exists error

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, linq

I use code first convention and mysql database in asp.net application. First I created a data model. Second I created database using add-migration  and update database. I see in MySQLWorkbench that my database was created. 
After that I run my app to see how database work. Before one of views is created I 'ask' database for a list of users. The problem is that during linq query to get list of users there is thrown an exception. Message is Table 'Events' already exists. I do not understand this error. Yes, all tables in the database exits. There is not direct relation between these to tables.
I have stared looking for the answer in the Internet. I found only one solution. I droped database, deleted all migrations, created new migration and update-database, but the this solutions does not solve the problem.

Any ideas?

This problem have number 1050 in MySQL.

In my Seed method I can insert objects into database, and it works. But during app is running the exception is thrown. I try:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Events;
REPAIR TABLE         Events;
```

I execute this queries in MySQLWorkbench and restart the application. Then I have "new" exception that: "Table 'Documents' already exists". When I try

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Documents;
REPAIR TABLE         Documents;
```

MySQLWorkbench: Error Code: 1217. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. So the problem still exists. Now I have exception "Table 'Documents' already exists". I check my Up method in migration class the first table which is created is Events, the second Documents. So I think that I should repair all tables, becouse in database-update command must create wrong database. But why it earlier works(?) I still do not know.

Comment: Show some code - copy your context class and the code you're using for fetching list of users

Comment: Try adding an empty migration with IgnoreChanges switch.. For example, "Add-Migration MyEmptyMigration -IgnoreChanges"

Comment: Nirman empty migration does not works. I did not delete database or migrations only: "Add-Migration MyEmptyMigration -IgnoreChanges" and update-database. The problem still exists.

Comment: Did the migration create a __MigrationHistory table and insert a record in your database? Add a line before your query to see if your model is up to date: if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false)) { you have a problem  }

Comment: Steave: I add this line. Database is compatybile with model.

Comment: This error is called mysql 1050... no solutions find in the Internet

Comment: What's your initializer look like? http://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-setup-mvc5-website-mysql-entity-framework-6-code-first-vs2013/

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Steave my context class is empty, becouse when I was using MyDbInitializer migrations did not works. Pawel http://pastebin.com/MaBrjmbp and inner exception is null.